# Issue with emogrifier on Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm Having 2 issues in my magento 1.9.1 app.

When I'm trying to proceed one page checkout my page redirects me to cart (but I can see in magento admin that order is placed with success)

Second issue is , when I'm tring to create invoice with comment and send it to customer i got blank page and invoice is not created. I can create invoice without sending e-mail without any error.

My system log shows: 1 Checkout issue

```
     2015-06-21T10:43:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: preg_replace_callback():      Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback  in /lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 269
2015-06-21T10:43:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback  in /lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 269
```

Invoice Issue - error is the same , so I suspect that problem is with Emogrifier.php file. I found that problem could be not enabled mbstring extension is php. In my Php mbstring is enabled.
I'm having magento 1.9.1 installation with PHP Version 5.4.23

**UPDATE 1**

Today I have upgraded emogrifier.lib to newest version , now my errors are:

```
2015-06-22T21:31:21+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 118
2015-06-22T21:31:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 118
```

Comment: did you try switching to default theme?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade Emogrifer lib? What version do You have?

Comment: @Claudiu In default view I'm also having this error 
Yes I upgraded Emogrifier lib ,  now my errors are (please follow update 1 in my post)